# Does this function define a distribution? $f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} e^{ -(x-n)^2 }$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Is this a continuous linear form on $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ ($C^\infty$ with compact support) such that for any sequence $\varphi_n\to0 \Rightarrow \langle T, \varphi_n \rangle \to 0$.

$\int_\mathbb{R}\sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}} e^{ -(x-m)^2 } \varphi_n(x) dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

I am guessing that it is not, so I could try to find a function for which this does not work, this is how far I have got, am I on the right track, should I try to use the translation of $\varphi_n$ for the counter example?

$\int_\mathbb{R}  e^{ -x^2 }  \sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \varphi_n(x+m) dx $

Comment: $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}e^{-(x-n)^2}$ is obviously a non-negative function bounded by $1+2\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-n^2}<\frac{16}{9}$. Do you really need anything else?

Comment: Yes I do, I could have worked out that it was non-negative and bounded. I did not know that that implies it is a distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $f$ is bounded, hence locally integrable (so it is a distribution ). For any x,

$$\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \exp( -(x-n)^2 ) \leq \sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} \exp( -(x-n)^2 ) $$

But $x-n = \{x\} + \lfloor x\rfloor - n = \{x\} + k$ (where $ \{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$)
$$\leq \sum_{k\in \Bbb Z} \exp( -(k+ \{x\})^2 ) $$

$$\leq \sum_{k\in \Bbb Z} \exp( -k^2 ) $$

$$\leq 2 \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} e^{-n^2} = C < +\infty $$

And every bounded function is a distribution :

Take a sequence $\varphi_n \to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}$, there exists a compact $K$ such that $\forall n, \text{Supp}(\phi_n) \subset K$, and we have

$$\left| \langle T_f, \varphi \rangle \right| = \left|  \int_{\Bbb R} f(x) \varphi_n(x) dx \right| = \left| \int_{K} f(x) \varphi_n(x) dx \right| \leq \| \varphi_n \|_\infty \| f \|_\infty  \mu( K ) \to 0 $$

Comment: Is your answer $f$ is bounded so it is locally integrable and so it is a distribution - here is the proof it is bounded?

If so - why is a locally integrable function a distribution? My definition is different to that.

Comment: @shilov : yes, it is my answer. See my edit for "why is a L1 loc function a distribution?" (very very very usefull result). Here I just have showed the weaker result for bounded functions, but you can use the same reasonning+Hölder to get the locally integrable case

Comment: that is very interesting thank you, could you direct me to a source for some similar results? For example what if we have $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} g(x)$ where $g(x)$ defines a distribution, is there anything we can say then?

Comment: @shilov : Your notation is lacking something. You're asking if a serie of functions that define a distributions is a distribution? I guess it depend wildly of the exact function, and I have no result specificly for distributions (just the usual result for functions, and the property that $\varphi \mapsto \int_{\Bbb R} f(x) \varphi(x) dx$ is a distribution if and only if $f\in L^1_{loc}$

Comment: What if I define $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} f(x) \varphi_n( x-m ) dx $, would that make sense?

Comment: @shilov : yes, this makes sense. And here this define a distribution if $f$ is integrable because $\sum_{m \in \Bbb Z} \varphi(x-m)$ is a $C^\infty$ function : as the support of $\varphi$ is compact, the sum is in fact a finite sum for each $x$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33905/discussion-between-shilov-and-tryss).